# Android Studio doesn't run

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

In my android studio, AVD Manager button is grey (disabled) and also in my build dropdown I do not see "make project". at the same time

ow can I build my android project?

Here's a screenshot of my app:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your project has it's file structure. this normally happens when importing other projects

Comment: The project should be fine since my partner in the project can load it. I'm going to put a screenshot of my code structure too.

Comment: I removed the root folder and now it's fine! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that the android sdk location is properly set in Project Structure Settings. (looking at the files in red probably error)

if you want to create avd then probably you can do

```
android create avd -n AvdName
adb list devices # to list devices
```

- Environment variable `$ANDROID_HOME` must be available and added to path (whatever your sdk location)
- adb is available in `$ANDROID_HOME/platfrom-tools` (you can add that to path too)

Comment: I did check SDK location it was fine. The problem was with my code structure but thank you anyways